# Usage of javascript setters/getters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I got my Cube class

```
class Cube{
    constructor(txt){
        this._text = txt;
    }
    get text(){
        return this._text;
    }
    set text(txt){
        this._text = txt;
    }
}
```

And I can implement something like that

```
let temp = new Cube('hello');
```

And at this point I don't understand the usage of setters and getters because I can do both:

```
temp.text = 'bye';
console.log(temp.text);//shows bye
console.log(temp._text);//shows bye
temp._text = 'hello again';
console.log(temp.text);//shows hello again
console.log(temp._text);//shows hello again
```

So I assume the only way I want to use setters when I want to do something like that:

```
set text(txt){
    this._text += txt;
}
```

Is there any other reason to use setters and getters?

Comment: Think about the fact that you can do anything you want to in a setter or getter function. They're just functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And at this point I don't understand the usage of setters and getters because I can do both: [using `text` and using `_text`]

Only because you've stored the value in a property on the instance. You don't have to do that, you could store it elsewhere:

```js
const Cube = function() {
  const privateData = new WeakMap();
  return class Cube {
    constructor(txt){
      privateData.set(this, {text: txt});
    }
    get text(){
      return privateData.get(this).text;
    }
    set text(txt){
      privateData.get(this).text = txt;
    }
  };
};

let temp = new Cube('hello');
temp.text = 'bye';
console.log(temp.text);  // shows bye
console.log(temp._text); // shows undefined
```

Or just make it harder (but not impossible) to use outside the class:

```js
const Cube = function() {
  const textProp = Symbol();
  return class Cube {
    constructor(txt){
        this[textProp] = txt;
    }
    get text(){
        return this[textProp];
    }
    set text(txt){
        this[textProp] = txt;
    }
  };
};

let temp = new Cube('hello');
temp.text = 'bye';
console.log(temp.text);  // shows bye
console.log(temp._text); // shows undefined
```

Also note that since `get` and `set` are *just functions*, you can do *anything* in them. For instance, maybe `set text` removes any leading and trailing whitespace. Maybe there *is* no `set text` and it only has a getter. Maybe setting `text` updates some other property. Maybe it records the change so you can provide "undo" on that change. Maybe it logs the change for debugging in debug builds.

The options are endless. The point is that by giving you a way to hook into property get/set operations, you can do anything with them. (Which of course you can both use and abuse... :-) )

In a comment you've asked:

> So in my case (1st code fragment), there is basically no need for get/set (as I don't want to modify my input and output)?

If you just want a normal, boring property (which is what we mostly want most of the time), there's no need for a getter/setter, just use a normal property:

```
class Cube {
    constructor(txt) {
        this.text = txt;
    }
}
```

And the great thing is, if you realize later you need a getter/setter, you can change it, and code written using `Cube` still works. :-)

Comment: Of course, in real life many people just creates setters and getters as the ones in the question for every property in the class (hey, even the IDE has an automation feature to do it!) because, you know, just making them public would break encapsulation ;-)

Comment: So in my case (1st code fragment), there is basically no need for get/set (as I don't want to modify my input and output)?

Comment: @user3006119: If you just want a normal, boring property (which is what we mostly want most of the time), there's no need for a getter/setter, just use a normal property. And the great thing is, if you realize later you need a getter/setter, you can change it, and code written using `Cube` still works. :-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but as you can see I can access those properties anyway, it gives me no encapsulation.

Comment: @user3006119: He was being sarcastic. :-)

Comment: Yes, I was being ironic, but it's something to take into account because I see it in live code all the time. In other words: not every pattern you see in the wild needs to necessarily make sense.